# Managing repo size of a fresh nopCommerce w/ Source download

Tags: git, nopcommerce, git-lfs, nopcommerce-4.3

While setting up the nopCommerce project, I didn't see any mention in the docs as to what files are loaded from NuGet and which are generated from the build. There are sizeable and numerous files in the `Presentation/Nop.Web` project and I am not sure how I should address them for version control. I can't imagine that it makes sense to commit `browscap.xml`, an 82MB file, to the repository.
I have added the default visual studio `.gitignore` and added most relevant binary files to `.gitattributes` but I want to be absolutely sure I'm not committing unnecessary files. To summarize in a question, between the large `browscap.xml` file and the kendo library, what can I do to minimize cruft getting committed to the repo? (IMO, 225MB+ is big for a repository and I need some justification for that)

[Presentation folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7EUD.png)

Comment: You don't have to commit anything that can be generated or downloaded during package restore or build. Apparently nopCommerce installs a 82 MB XML file to recognize web crawlers, and it requires you to commit this to source control.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's just it, there isn't a list of what was pulled in statically and what is being restored. There are so many ways that files could be restored that it's unreasonable to expect every potential developer to dig and diff their way to enumerating these files.

Comment: I don't know the development model for nopCommerce. Is it self-contained, does it get pulled in as a NuGet package, or does it expect each developer to install it manually for each project? You could look into their docs, if any, how you're expected to handle this. Maybe this: https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/60398/working-with-git-source-control